# maven repository download sha files

Tags: maven, jar, repository, offline, sha

I am trying to setup maven as build tool on a platform without internet access.

Is it ok if I just copy the contents of ~/.m2 in the target platform.

Except from jar files I also see following in the repository structure:

XX.jar.lastUpdated

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Wed May 09 12:54:27 EEST 2018
https\://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/.error=
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1525859667446
https\://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/.lastUpdated=1525859553024
```

xx.jar/sha1:

5a3158b41dcc4d88b82d08b4b5802c54f396bd49p3700633

xx.pom:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <description>scalatest</description>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <name>scalatest</name>
    <organization>
        <name>org.scalatest</name>
    </organization>
    <url>http://www.scalatest.org</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>the Apache License, ASL Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:scalatest/scalatest.git</connection>
        <developerConnection> scm:git:git@github.com:scalatest/scalatest.git </developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>bvenners</id>
            <name>Bill Venners</name>
            <email>bill@artima.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>gcberger</id>
            <name>George Berger</name>
            <email>george.berger@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>cheeseng</id>
            <name>Chua Chee Seng</name>
            <email>cheeseng@amaseng.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalactic_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalacheck</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalacheck_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.4</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-sbt</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-interface</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.7</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pegdown</groupId>
            <artifactId>pegdown</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

xx.pom.lastUpdated:

```
NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Wed May 09 12:51:01 EEST 2018
https\://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/.error=
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1525859461330
https\://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/.lastUpdated=1525859461229
```

xx.pom.sha1:

8858e7d282548a9c0644cfe1e47d8189cb57f4a7p3700633

Comment: Ahm...and what is exactly your question?